# Web scraping - Password Power BI

Tags: python, web-scraping

I use python3(Kivy, beautifulSoup, kivy etc).

My company uses PowerBI to assign tasks to everyone. My idea is to make an app so  when they make changes in the scheduled it would update in my app.

The problem that I am having is that I cannot take the information from PowerBI because it is a secure site and my user and password is needed.

Is there any way to obtain the info?

Thank you in advance,

Best regards,

Santiago

Comment: You clearly said why you can't do this through straightforward programming: this is a secure interface.  It's is not appropriate to ask us to help you circumvent your company's security.

Comment: You need to discuss your application with the appropriate people within your company.  They would need to grant you appropriate permissions through the PowerBI API.

Comment: I am not doing nothing strange only trying to improve and learning in the process. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium to grab html elements and send characters into them.
This way you can automate the task of logging in everytime so you do not have to.

Make sure to

```
pip install selenium
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this way!!

Answer (score -1):

If you have your own username and password to login you might be able to use Selenium to get in and then obtain the information from there.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io

Comment: Perfect, I will try this way so! Thank you very much!